# Bootstrap Tab Pane to Slide Left?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, slide

I've implemented a Photoshop design into HTML using Bootstrap (my first time with bootstrap). That is a single page website and have 4 sections (actually pages). Every section have multiple pages which I've have showed in Tab Panel using Bootstrap's tabbable class. It's working fine, I want a sliding effect for every tab to display it's content.  Means, if a section contains 3 tabs and I click on the 2nd tab, the next tab's content appear as sliding effect. Is there only class name to add?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it is what you was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about it

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="tab-container" class="span6 offset1">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
              <li class="active"><a href="#options" data-toggle="tab">Options</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#information" data-toggle="tab">Information</a></li>
              <li class="disabled"><a href="#payment" data-toggle="tab">Payment</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="options">
                    <div class="well">
                    <form id="frmtype1" action="" name="frmtype1" method="post">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Registration Options</legend>

                            <label for="Reg_type1" class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type1" value="1"/>
                        Registering myself with credit card or bank account
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label for="Reg_type2" class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type2" value="2"/>
                        Registering multiple people using credit card or bank account
                        </label>
                        <br>
                        <label for="Reg_type3" class="radio">
                            <input type="radio" name="Reg_type" id="Reg_type3" value="3"/>
                        Registering using a purchase order
                        </label>
                        </fieldset>
                                <button class="btn-demo btn" data-activate="#information">Continue</button>
                        <span class="help-inline" style="display:none;">Please choose an option</span>
                    </form> 
                    </div><!--/.well -->
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="information">
                    <div class="well">
                    <form name="everything" id="frmtype2" action="" method="post"><p>Some content to give this pane a little bit of bulk</p>
                         <button class="btn-demo btn" data-activate="#payment" type="submit">Continue</button>
                    </form>
                    </div><!--/.well -->
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="payment">
                    <div class="well">
                    <p>Some content for the 3rd pane.</p>     
                    </div><!-- .well -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div><!-- /#tab-container --> </div><!-- /.container -->
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var selector;
var selectorID;

activateTab('#myTab a:first');

function activateTab(selectorID) 
{
    $(selectorID).tab('show')
        .closest('.disabled').removeClass('disabled');    
}

function deactivateTab(selector) 
{
    $(selector).off('click.twbstab')
        .closest('li').addClass('disabled');
}

$('.btn-demo').on('click',function() {
    selector = '#myTab a[href="'+$(this).data('activate')+'"]';
    selectorID = $(selector).attr('href');
});

var val1 = $('#frmtype1').validate(
{
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}, 
    // prevent the standard error message from showing, rather you use the inline-text
    rules: {
        'Reg_type': {
            required: true
        }
    }
});

// validate 1st form
$('#frmtype1').submit(function(e) 
{
    // validate the first page
    if(val1.form()) {
        $('.help-inline').hide();
        activateTab(selector);
    } else {
        $('.help-inline').show();
    }
    return false;
});

// validate 2nd form
$('#frmtype2').submit(function(e) 
{
    // validate the second page
    activateTab(selector);
    return false;
});


// if 2nd or 3rd tab is clicked, validate as if the form was submitted
$('#myTab li:eq(1) a, #myTab li:eq(2) a').click(function(e) 
{
    selectorID = $(this).attr('href');
    // validate the first page
    if(val1.form()) {
        $('.help-inline').hide();
        activateTab(this);
        $(selectorID).tab('show');
    } else {
        $('.help-inline').show();
    }
    return false;
});

// re-position all tab-panes, except the active pane, so that they are prepared for the slide effect
$(".tab-pane").css("position", "relative");
$(".tab-pane").not(".active").animate({
    left: "1000px"
});

// perform slide effect
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show', function (e) {
    lastPane = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('href');
    $(lastPane).animate({left: "1000px"}, 300)
    currPane = $(e.target).attr('href');
    $(currPane).animate({left: "0px"}, 300);
});
```

[JSFidle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/ymxn4/)

Comment: Upvoted - Clean. The only edit I would make is to the CSS, as the overflow hidden does not work with that selector. Use '.tab-content {
    overflow:hidden;
}'

Comment: Demo is not work on chrome.